# wpf : handle itemscontrol child mouse wheel event when mouse focus on child control

Tags: wpf

Need to handle itemscontrol child mouse wheel event when mouse focus on child control.If mouse focus on itemscontrol scroll viewer then that scroll should work.Please help to achieve this.

Note : I am able to route event from child itemscontrol.But inreverse need answer..

Answer (score 1):

Add a event for Child Control "PreviewMouseWheel"

```
private void ChildControl_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            ItemControl.ScrollToVerticalOffset(MainScroll.VerticalOffset - e.Delta);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Comment: Code is not working.Compile error for ScrollToVerticalOffset . Can you please give in detail ?

Comment: Item Control have a scroll Viewer.That (Scroll Viewer Name).ScrollToVerticalOffset((Scroll Viewer Name).VerticalOffset - e.Delta);